# Cancel action executing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

I have a page with filters and 2 buttons: Generate and Cancel. So, when I click on the Generate button I go to Results action. When I click on the Cancel button I want to cancel my previous reqeust in code and in database.

Some code (I use .NET 4.0, MVC 4)

ResultsController.cs:

```
public Task<PartialViewResult> Results(int id)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("token", tokenSource);

            Task<PartialViewResult> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                return ResultsRepository.PrepareViewModel(id);
            }, tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(x => PartialView("Results", x.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("task", task);

            return task;
        }

public JsonResult CancelResultsByMonthGeneration(int id, DateTime selectedMonth)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["token"] as CancellationTokenSource;
            Task<PartialViewResult> task = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["task"] as Task<PartialViewResult>;

            try {
                if (tokenSource != null) {
                    tokenSource.Cancel();
                    task.Wait();
                }
            } 
            finally {
                task.Dispose();
                tokenSource.Dispose();
            }

            return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

ResultsRepository.cs

```
public ResultsViewModel PrepareViewModel(int id)
            {
                // use Entity Framework to call stored procedure
            }
```

So, expected result: if I cancel report generating request should be cancelled, no data is shown.

Main question: can I cancel request using method tokenSource.Cancel() ?
Or should I use ThrowIfCancellationRequested() method (where?)

Comment: **When I click on the Cancel button I want to cancel my previous reqeust in code and in database.** This is too vague. You would have to write pages about how you store your data and how generate queue your request. And even then, this is not an open and shut case.\

Comment: Ok, we can leave database request cancelling. Main question still is "can I cancel request using method tokenSource.Cancel() ? Or should I use ThrowIfCancellationRequested() method (where?)"

Comment: Now that's an excellent question. I would guess you can call tokenSource.Cancel(). But I haven't so I'm just guessing here. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I have tried tokenSource.Cancel() - task wasn't cancelled.

Comment: As I understand, Cancel() method only markes task as cancelled. And I need manually check IsCancellationRequested property

Comment: In order to cancel, the method `ResultsRepository.PrepareViewModel` would need to accept a `CancellationToken` input. Or at the very least you'd need your task to check the `IsCancellationRequested` property (as you've correctly surmised). Checking for a cancellation *after* `PrepareViewModel` has run is presumably of little value though, since that's the expensive operation?